# How to change individual characters in string on C?

Tags: c, arrays, character

Trying to make some basic hangman code to practice learning C but I can't seem to change individual characters in the program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length, a, x;
    x = 0;
    char gWord[100];
    char word[100] = "horse";

    length = strlen(word) - 1;
    for(a = 0; a<= length; a = a + 1){
        gWord[a] = "_";
        printf("%s", gWord[a]);
    }
    printf("%s", gWord);
}
```

when I try to run this it just prints (null) for every time it goes through the loop. It's probably a basic fix but I'm new to C and can't find anything about it online

Comment: Try `printf("%c", gWord[a]);`, as items in the `gWord` array are characters and not string any more. Also, if you want to print the whole `gWord` as a string (i.e. "%s"), you have to append a '\0' character to it.

Comment: 1) Use `%c` for printing individual chars 2) You need to zero-terminate `gWord`before printing it as a string

Answer (score 6):

To print character instead of string change:

```
printf("%s", gWord[a]);
```

to:

```
printf("%c", gWord[a]);
```

but before that change also:

```
gWord[a] = "_";
```

to:

```
gWord[a] = '_';
```

The last problem is that you were assigning a string literal to a single character.

#### Edit:

Also as @4386427 pointed out, you never zero-terminate `gWord` before printing it later on with `printf("%s", gWord)`. You should change the last line from:

```
printf("%s", gWord);
```

to:

```
gWord[a] = '\0';
printf("%s", gWord);
```

because otherwise this would very likely lead to a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
printf("%s", gWord[a]);
```

Must be

```
printf("%c", gWord[a]);
```

To print a char, **c** is the right specifier. **s** is only for whole strings and takes char pointers.

Comment: `length = strlen(word) - 1`, So the original for loop is correct.

Comment: Right, sorry for the mixup. I'll fix it post-haste.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any warning message('s) when compiling your code?

Since you are learning C language, one suggestion - **Never ignore any warning message given by the compiler, they are there for some reason.**

Three problems in your code:

**First:**
Assigning string to a character:

```
gWord[a] = "_";
```

`gWord` is an array of `100` characters and `gWord[a]` is a character at location `a` of `gWord` array. Instead, you should do

```
gWord[a] = '_';
```

**Second:**
Using wrong format specifier for printing a character:

```
printf("%s", gWord[a]);
        ^^
```

For printing a character you should use `%c` format specifier:

```
printf("%c", gWord[a]);
```

**Third:**
Missed adding null terminating character at the end in `gWord` and printing it:

```
printf("%s", gWord);
```

In C language, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters **terminated by a null character '\0'**. The `%s` format specifier is used for character string and by default characters are printed until the ending null character is encountered. So, you should make sure to add `'\0'` at the end of `gWord` after the `for` loop finishes:

```
gWord[a] = '\0';
```

Apart from these, there are couple of more things -
This statement:

```
length = strlen(word) - 1;
```

I do not see any reason of subtracting `1` from the `word` length. The `strlen` return the length of string without including the terminating null character itself. So, the `strlen(word)` will give output `5`. Now you are subtracting `1` from this and running loop till `<= length` may confuse the reader of the code. You should simply do:

```
    length = strlen(word);
    for(a = 0; a < length; a = a + 1){
     ....
     ....
```

Also, the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t` and the `size_t` is an unsigned type. So, you should use the variable of type `size_t` to receive `strlen()` return value.

Last but not least, make sure to not to have any unused variables/parameters in your program. You are not using `argc` and `argv` anywhere in your program. If you are using `gcc` compiler then compile it with `-Wall -Wextra` options. You will find that compiler will report all the unused variables/parameters. So, if not using `argc` and `argv` then you should simply give `void` in the parameter list of `main()` function.

Putting these all together, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t length, a;
    char gWord[100];
    char word[100] = "horse";

    length = strlen(word);
    for(a = 0; a < length; a = a + 1) {
        gWord[a] = '_';
        printf("%c", gWord[a]);
    }

    gWord[a] = '\0';
    printf ("\n");
    printf("%s\n", gWord);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, your code is alright @Blookey. But logically, no actually.

Let me point out 3 places which are causing the undesired behavior in your code:

1. `gWord[a] = "_";`  Observe this line. You have specified the `_` in **" "**. In case you are unaware of this fact, each individual element of a string is a character. And each character is supposed to be given in **' '**, i.e., single quotes and not double quotes.
2. `printf("%s", gWord[a]);` A similar error again. `gWord[a]` is a character, not a string. Hence you need to print it using the format specifier `%c` instead of `%s` which is for string instead.
3. A string, any string is supposed to end with a NULL, which is **`\0`**  (backslashZERO). That is what differentiates an array of characters from a string. So just add the following line once you finish loading characters into `gWord[]`.

   `gWord[a] = '\0';`

Here is the complete code, just with the 3 changes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length, a, x;
    x = 0;
    char gWord[100];
    char word[100] = "horse";

    length = strlen(word) - 1;
    for(a = 0; a<= length; a = a + 1){
        gWord[a] = '_';
        printf("%c ", gWord[a]);
    }
    gWord[a] = '\0';
    printf("\n%s", gWord);
}
```

Here is the OUTPUT:

> _ _ _ _ _ .
>
> _____.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int length, a, x;
x = 0;
char gWord[100] = {0};
char word[100] = "horse"; /*note that if the array in place strlen +1 is not nulled  before using strlen you might not get the correct result*/

length = strlen(word) - 1;/*strln will return 5, that is the letters inn the string the pointer is pointing to until the first terminator '\0'*/
for(a = 0; a<= length; a = a + 1){
gWord[a] = '_'; /* if you use "_" it will try to fit in the chars '_' and '\0' to each char slot of the array*/
printf("%c", gWord[a]); /* %s looks for a string to print while here there are single chars to print*/
}
printf("\n");/*you can print the hole string like this */
printf("%s", gWord); 

return 0;/*and remember that main function should always have a return value*/
}
```